# Eliminate repeating numbers like 33,44,333 in given array

Tags: c++, arrays

Given a series of numbers with only 3 and 4 Find the nth number in the series. First few numbers in the number system are 3,4,33,34,43,44,333,334,433,434,444,3333,3334,3343,3344,..

For Example: To find fourth number
    answer is 34.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void nuS(int n)
{
    int nu[100],i=0;
    n=n+1;
    while(n!=1)
    {
        if(n%2==0)
        nu[i++]=5;
        else
        nu[i++]=6;
        n/=2;

    }
    while(i--)
    cout<<nu[i];
    cout<<endl;
}

int main() {
    int n,a[200];
    cin>>n;
    nuS(n);
    return 0;
}
```

I have done program for this previous problem.
Help me to avoid repeating numbers and initial numbers in an array

For example :
i need a list like  34, 43, 334, 343, 344, 434, ..

Comment: can you show me whats your desired output?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for declaring: `a[200]`?

Comment: Do you want to work out on this same method of yours or it is okay if I suggest a better method?

Comment: Why are you saving `5` and `6` in `nu`? How is it helping you to generate the desired number in the series?